# Removing Layout will default to _ViewStart, so why section name is not found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Let's say I have this view:

```
@model App.ViewModels.Unicorn

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id='#unicorns'>...</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unicorns")
}
```

**If** removing the `Layout` in the view will default it's layout to the one specified in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file then why is it complaining about `Cannot resolve section 'Scripts'`?

EDIT:
I do have my section on my layout page:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Please **do note** this is **not** case sensitive, since it's been working **with** the `@section Scripts` uppercase 'S' **and** `@RenderSection("scripts` lower 's'.

Comment: **I have resharper v6 installed**, I don't believe it may be a resharper issue, thats why I didn't tag it.

Comment: Do you have a `Scripts` section defined in this `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, but of course I do, I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: In your `_Layout` the section is called `scripts`, not `Scripts`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov please read the full question, edit included.

Comment: If you remove the `scripts` section from your view which Layout gets rendered? Is it the one you expect (`~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`)? Put some easily distinguishable text in it and see if it renders the correct layout. I suspect that some other layout is being used in which you do not have this section registered. Also what's inside your `_ViewStart.cshtml` and where is this file located? Is it inside `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`?

Comment: Note that Resharper will also flag this error if you omit the tilde (`~`) from the start of the path.

Answer (score 3):

Even though .Net doesn't care about the case sensitivity Resharper does. Changing it to lowercase will fix the issue.

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unicorns")
}
```

Comment: As of R# 8.0,, at least, this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: This did not fix it for me as well. I have R# 8.1. I'm having the same issue as well. Seemed to appear when I updated my NuGet packages for the Razor engine. Does anyone have a solution?